# Memory leaks in a simple Rcpp function

Tags: c++, r, memory-leaks, rcpp

I am developing a package in R that I would like to convert to Rcpp for better performance. I'm new to Rcpp (and C++ in general.) My problem is that the Rcpp function I've written works fine if I run it many times with one set of arguments, but if I try to loop it over many combinations of arguments, it springs memory leaks and causes the R session to abort.

Here is the code in R, which holds up well to any test I throw at it:

```
raw_noise <- function(timesteps, mu, sigma, phi) {
   delta <- mu * (1 - phi)
   variance <- sigma^2 * (1 - phi^2)
   noise <- vector(mode = "double", length = timesteps)
   noise[1] <- c(rnorm(1, mu, sigma))
   for (i in (1:(timesteps - 1))) {
     noise[i + 1] <- delta + phi * noise[i] + rnorm(1, 0, sqrt(variance))
  }
   return(noise)
}
```

Here is the code in Rcpp, using three [Rcpp sugar functions](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) (pow, sqrt, rnorm):

```
NumericVector raw_noise(int timesteps, double mu, double sigma, double phi) {
  double delta = mu * (1 - phi);
  double variance = pow(sigma, 2.0) * (1 - pow(phi, 2.0));
  NumericVector noise(timesteps);
  noise[0] = R::rnorm(mu, sigma);
  for(int i = 0; i < timesteps; ++i) {
    noise[i+1] = delta + phi*noise[i] + R::rnorm(0, sqrt(variance));
  }
  return noise;
}
```

What really confuses me is that this code runs without problems:

```
library(purrr)
rerun(10000, raw_noise(timesteps = 30, mu = 0.5, sigma = 0.2, phi = 0.3))
```

But when I run this code:

```
test_loop <- function(timesteps, mu, sigma, phi, replicates) {
  params <- cross_df(list(timesteps = timesteps, phi = phi, mu = mu, sigma = 
sigma))
  for (i in 1:nrow(params)) {
    print(params[i,])
    pmap(params[i,], raw_noise)
  }
}
library(purrr)
test_loop(timesteps=c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), mu=c(0.2, 0.5), sigma=c(0.2, 0.5),
      phi=c(0, 0.1))
```

More often than not, the R session aborts and RStudio crashes altogether. But sometimes I manage to catch this error message before the R session aborts:

> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :    GC encountered a node
>   (0x10db7af50) with an unknown SEXP type: NEWSXP at memory.c:1692

As I understand it, NEWSXP is an exotic object type in R that doesn't come up very often. What's happening looks to me like a memory leak, but I'm not at all sure how to fix it. Like I said, I'm new to Rcpp and C++ generally so I'd appreciate any nudges in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an out of bounds error:

```
for(int i = 0; i < timesteps; ++i)
```

causes

```
noise[i+1]
```

to exceed the defined range since *C++* indices start at 0 and not 1.

---

For example, `0` to `timesteps - 1` has a length of `timesteps` and, thus, is okay.

but

`0` to `timesteps` would have a length of `timesteps + 1`

This can be seen if you change `noise[i+1]` to `noise(i+1)`, which performs a bounds check on the requested index.

```
Error in raw_noise(100, 2, 3, 0.2) : 
  Index out of bounds: [index=100; extent=100].
```

---

To address this, make the following change:

```
NumericVector raw_noise(int timesteps, double mu, double sigma, double phi) {
  double delta = mu * (1 - phi);
  double variance = pow(sigma, 2.0) * (1 - pow(phi, 2.0));
  NumericVector noise(timesteps);
  noise[0] = R::rnorm(mu, sigma);

  // change here
  for(int i = 0; i < timesteps - 1; ++i) { // 1 less time step

    noise[i+1] = delta + phi*noise[i] + R::rnorm(0, sqrt(variance));
  }
  return noise;
}
```

Comment: There are two hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Comment: Thanks so much. I should have thought of this, since when I switch between R and Python I often forget about the discrepancies in how the languages index (start at 0 vs. start at 1). I just never suspected it because the code ran fine when I didn't change the arguments.